# Regex extract all characters between keywords

Tags: regex

I have a line like this:

```
One Two Three ABC CDE - 26/01/2014 18:37:42 - S123456 - Four Five Six
```

And would like to remove the following:

```
ABC CDE - dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss - S123456 -
```

The above line always includes **ABC** and **S123456 -** (but S123456 could change, ie. S987654). Remove text starting from **ABC** to the last **-** (dash).

So the following is left:

```
One Two Three Four Five Six
```

I have this as a start but its not working for me:

```
(?:.*?\s -\s){3}(.*)
```

Would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear to me... how exactly would you identify the portion of your string you want to remove? Will it always **start with `ABC`** and **end with `456 -`**? Or will it always be **preceded by `Three`** and **followed by `Four`**? I think that we could use some more specific information in order to help you :)

Comment: @ccjmne added more info thx

Comment: Great, thank you! My reponse is below, I just tested it before posting it, so I'm pretty sure it's working well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect, thank you for adding the information I asked for :)

Try matching:

```
ABC(?<!S\d{6} -).*S\d{6} -
```

And replacing by an **empty string**.

---

How it works? It matches something that:

- starts with `ABC`
- ends with `SXXXXXX -` where each `X` is a **numeric** (`\d`).
- contains anything (`.*`) except `SXXXXXX -`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Without a clear indication of your long term requirements, I could simply match the example like this:

`A.*-\s`

---

**Output**

```
One Two Three Four Five Six
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here's an RE that is fairly general ...

```
echo "One Two Three ABC CDE - 26/01/2014 18:37:42 - S123456 - Four Five Six" | sed -E 's/[A-Z]{3} [A-Z]{3} - .* - S[0-9]{6} - //'

One Two Three Four Five Six
```